# Data Driven routes/pages/subpages in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

This is a simplified example...

If I want to pass from a route (the redirect is if the subpage isn't specified):

```
    <Route path="/activities" component={PageElements.SectionPage} onEnter={App.RequireAuth}>
        <IndexRoute component={Activities.Redirect}/>
        <Route path="/activities/:page" component={Activities.PageSelector}  />
    </Route>
```

And then do some magic in PageElements:

```
export class SectionPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
            <SiteSubHeader location={this.props.location} />
            {this.props.children}
        </div>
    } 
}
```

and then want to render things inside of a page selector for a section:

```
export class PageSelector extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        this.pages = {
        "overview": <Overview />,
      // "overview": Overview,  // also doesn't work
        "another": <Another />,
        "yetanother": <YetAnother />
    }
        var page = this.props.params.page;
        return this.pages.page;
        // also a million variants of return <div>{this.pages.page}</div> don't work
        // this kind of thing DOES work:
        //   if (page == "overview") return <Overview />
    }

    const Overview = () => {
      return  <div>Overview</div> 
    } 

 }
```

Basically  I'm looking for a way to easily generate a number of pages and subpages out of data structures. They are all pretty different and will be different layouts with subcomponents etc. Am I going about this the wrong way? I don't want to have a ton of ifs in the render method.

> invariant.js:38Uncaught Invariant Violation: PageSelector.render(): A
>   valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned
>   undefined, an array or some other invalid object.

I feel like I'm fighting against React here so I'm probably doing something wrong. Any help would be appreciated.